My html cell (td) border color is overiding the table border color. How can I prevent this?
I have a table with one row and four cells.
I want that inside the table the td border colour is active, but the table outer border color should be as defined in the table css properties.
For achieving that I have added !important to the table border definition. But still the td border definition is overriding it. How can I prevent this?


.td_table {
  border: 1pt solid #B5B5B5;
}

.table_1 {
  border: 1px solid black !important;
}
<table class="table_1">
  <tr max-height="35">
    <td class="td_table">...</td>
    <td class="td_table">...</td>
    <td class="td_table">...</td>
    <td class="td_table">...</td>
  </tr>
</table>




Change to border: 1pt solid red and see why. You change the border of the table, not the cells



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Table Border Example</title>
<style>
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse; /* This property collapses the table borders into a single border */
    border: 2px solid blue;    /* Set the table border color */
  }
  td {
    border: 1px solid red;     /* Set the cell border color */
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>



To ensure that the table border color overrides the cell border color in HTML, you can use the border-collapse CSS property on the table element. This property specifies whether the table borders should be collapsed into a single border or separated.
